# Does in-app rate app pop-up appear for the users already has rated on App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I was wondering if in-app rate app pop-up appear for the users already has rated on App Store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the rating prompt shown via [`SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/3566727-requestreview) does not show for users who have already given feedback.

From Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/patterns/ratings-and-reviews/#best-practices) (emphasis mine):

> When you identify places in your experience where it makes sense to ask for feedback, the system checks for previous feedback and — **if there isn’t any** — displays an in-app prompt that asks for a rating and an optional written review.